# How to create distance between textbox to its parent form in c#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, textbox, buffer

I have a winform with labels and text boxes that looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmvlK.png)

I used the anchor property to make the "comment" text box adjust to the form if it changes, but now it sticks to its border

How can I change it and set a buffer between them?
I looked everywhere online but couldn't find a solution :(

update:
Here is the code to the element

```
var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            if (doc == null) return;
            var ed = doc.Editor;

 _input_comment = new WinForms.TextBox();
            _input_comment.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
            _input_comment.SetBounds(x_axis_position, y_pointer, 100, 40);
            _input_comment.Size = new Size(216, 60);
            _input_comment.Multiline = true;
            _input_comment.WordWrap = true;
            _input_comment.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
            _uc.Controls.Add(_input_comment);
```

Comment: _it sticks to its border_ it really shouldn't. Did you set a minimalSize?

Comment: Using `SetBounds` and `Size` with completely different sizes can't be right. Why don't you define this textbox with the winforms designer?